# Load an image from URL (URL stored in database) into Picturebox

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a basic search function, so basically you search a doctors name, e.g "Bob" and their First Name, Last Name and the picture of them. But what I want to do is store the URL of the image on the database and somehow display that image in a PictureBox when they doctors name is searched.

So far this is what I have:

```
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;database=docdatabase");
        string Query = ("SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE FirstName='" + textBox1.Text + "'");
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
        MySqlDataReader mdr = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (mdr.Read())
        {
            textBox2.Text = (mdr["FirstName"].ToString());
            textBox3.Text = (mdr["LastName"].ToString());
            textBox4.Text = (mdr["Verified"].ToString());
            pictureBox1.Image = (mdr["Cert"].ToString()); //The Image
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No doctor by that name! Try again.");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the

```
PictureBox.Load(string URL)
```

Method

> Sets the ImageLocation to the specified URL and displays the image indicated."

So in your case it'd be

```
pictureBox1.Load(mdr["Cert"].ToString());
```